# how to find the multilevel index of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a library that returns a seemingly 'flat' dataframe, that has a few columns and an index column - something like:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"s": ["a", "b", "c"], "A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6]})
df = df.set_index("s")
```

however, when I print `df.xs`, it turns out the columns "A" and "B" has a label (an index) as well. This leads to confusing results when calling methods like `pandas.melt(df)`, because in the melted df the named index for `A, B` columns appears instead of `variable`, which is what should be there if the columns were not grouped or named in any way.

How can I print all the indices/named columns used in a dataframe? And then reset these? superficially it looks like `df` has only the `s` index column and `A, B` columns but there's more state/hierarchical indexing stored in there that I don't know how to access.
I can't construct a simple self-contained example of this because I do not know how this dataframe was built.

Comment: As far as making a self-contained example,  you could try using `to_csv()` on the DataFrame to write it out and see if anything interesting appears.  If not that, try `to_pickle()` because that's a more full-featured serialization that may allow us to get a truer copy of your data.

Comment: Not sure where the confusion is here, you have upper and lower case letters in your index and column names, if you didn't want that you could just reset the index or assign to a new generated index